# Javascript, why is the alert returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why is my alert returning an undefined result in the following JavaScript function:

```
function tabs(data = null){
  for(var i = 0; i<= data.result.length ; i++){
    $.each(data.result[i], function(key, value){
      alert(data.result[i].key)
    });
  }
}
```

i want to optimize my code 
i want to replace this code by another dynamic solution : 
i want to optimize this code

```
alert(value.text_id); 
alert(value.text_content);
alert(value.text_image_link);
```

Comment: because array indices start at 0 and and at `.length - 1` ... i.e. an array of length 4 has indices 0, 1, 2, 3 .... use `<` not `<=`

Comment: OBO (off by one) error

Answer (score 1):

Your alert returns undefined because the array index starts at 0 and ends at `length - 1`. You are using `i <= length` but that will cause you to go out of bounds therefore you should use `i < length`.

Comment: So you have replaced `i<= data.result.length` with `i< data.result.length` and still have the same issue? Are you getting a different error message? It would help if you posted your error message to the question.

Comment: yes 
i want to do like that value.key.
normaly to display a value i have to write  value.text_id.

Comment: i want to replace the text_id by the key variable to be dynamic

Comment: I do not understand. Your question is that alert is returning undefined, correct? Can I see all of your code?

Comment: i want to write value.key like that   since key is the json array keys

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not post the code in the comments. Also please rewrite your question of what you are asking specially. What it says now has nothing to do with what you are saying. You may be best just opening up a new question.

Comment: I think I understand your question. Please mark my answer as correct as it fixes the question you asked first then open a new one with your new question about returning value.key. I will help you there. I will be on the lookout for it.

Comment: You are currently asking why it is undefined and also how to optimize your code. They are two separate questions. Please create a new question. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I will be glad to help but you need to follow SO rules.